# Trouble submitting image URL from Reddit using requests.get()

Tags: python, image, get, python-requests

I am trying to submit an image URL from Reddit.com to a vision API using `requests.get()` in Python but I am running into difficulties in what could be a simple error on my part. The `requests.get()` request is successful when the link points to an explicit *.jpg, e.g., `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2b/Beef_fillet_steak_with_mushrooms.jpg/800px-Beef_fillet_steak_with_mushrooms.jpg`, but unsuccessful when the link points to what I perceive to be a soft link, e.g., `https://preview.redd.it/9xu97c5snpr51.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=e68c02166f6fd21a47a957b187b98b92608f54a9`. Note that when pasted into a browser, both links work fine.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I might preprocess the second link so it is handled like the first link? I would like to eventually have this code run remotely, so avoiding having to download the file locally is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

You can access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

i = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```